# Typescript does't throw an error if a function returns the wrong interface

Tags: typescript

This isn't an issue when I call the function directly, but in this case, the Typescript can't catch the error while calling it internally via another function such as the example below:

```js
const updatePerson = ({
  name,
  onCurrentPerson,
}: {
  name: Person['name'];
  onCurrentPerson: (personValue: Person) => Person;
}) => {
  const updatedPeople = people.map((currentPerson) => {
    if (currentPerson.name !== name) return currentPerson;

    return onCurrentPerson(currentPerson);
  });
  return updatedPeople
};
```

[See the code below on the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmRycDVJArmQEbQEC+BAghy1kABwhZxAG3boo2EAG0AusgC8yZXlIVqAIgBSWABYgDAGhZtqAJgAM-VUJEgxHcQBM4kBUs1kAApCYj0IS2YcAGEOKCgIcH8cSP5qUJJyeUwcZQBycLzVAG4okFj4xLBkkGogyUUcADU4GQ5sxpAASk0APjQckFL+Ho1+jLcPb18IL3RpOUDJBYgAOjI4cSCghDiEpMHR8eZiYBhg3cqDztXw5ABCDS1wnoSwONxL-erB0pPkN4fZAxPZVGo7UHXJRdUrEEawgEQd5QXCeHyQOZSWQQAR-NEzcEZcKGEzmKxlCrfGp1L5gw59fD-SZgCSDag1QIZYirHm0qEpf6sdh2OyRYjEGRwEAMDhCwwAUWlMmAGFMBmQAHoNcgADwAWj1yAAKqYoFgAO4YFi4aBmqD-fgI4iAlGszoI-ipGFCfF+QYhZjE5DGMwWMXA8qQn6dGlRmpHYJc5A81Z86NKcPEOXIEWZ5CS6Wy2zBxUMZWq9Wa7X6w0AESwECtICwLLApot1uQtqw9vFyBGXuKQA)

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const people: Person[] = [{name: "John", age: 20}]

const updatePerson = ({
  name,
  onCurrentPerson,
}: {
  name: Person['name'];
  onCurrentPerson: (personValue: Person) => Person;
}) => {
  const updatedPeople = people.map((currentPerson) => {
    if (currentPerson.name !== name) return currentPerson;

    return onCurrentPerson(currentPerson);
  });
  return updatedPeople
};

updatePerson({
  name: "John",
  onCurrentPerson: (currentPerson) => {
    const person: Person = {
    ...currentPerson,
    age: 22,
    language: "English" // <-- Throws an error
    };
    return person;
  },
});


updatePerson({
  name: "John",
  onCurrentPerson: (currentPerson) => ({
    ...currentPerson,
    age: 22,
    language: "English"  // <-- Does not throw an error
    }),
});
```

As you can see my current solution demands me to check the value before returning it:

```js
onCurrentPerson: (currentPerson) => {
  const person: Person = {
    ...currentPerson,
    age: 22,
    language: "English" // <-- Throws an error
  };
  return person;
},
```

I would like to understand why this error doesn't show when I call it like the example below:

```js
updatePerson({
  name: "John",
  onCurrentPerson: (currentPerson) => ({
    ...currentPerson,
    age: 22,
    language: "English"  // <-- Does not throw an error
  }),
});
```

What am I missing and how can I reinforce the type without having to check the type before returning the value?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

The fix you need will be shipped with TS 4.9 : `satifies`

```
updatePerson({
  name: "John",
  onCurrentPerson: (currentPerson) => ({
    ...currentPerson,
    age: 22,
    language: "English"  // <-- Does throw an error
    } satisfies Person),
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and for the TS docs you shared. I was looking for a solution that allows me to make the `updatePerson` more restricted so I don't have to check the type before returning the values such as `const person: Person = {}` or `{} satisfies Person`. Are you saying that is not possible and I would need to use `{} satisfies Person` every time I need to use `updatePerson( { onCurrentPerson })`?